# RadioButton has a white background when not focused?

Tags: wpf, radio-button, .net-4.5

Radio button when I manually click the radio buttons [image]

Radio button when I press another button to set the choice 
[image]

Seems to be when the radio button isn't focused then get this white square box around

Styling for the RB:

```
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF3E3E3E" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="12">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </BulletDecorator>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="RadioMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="RadioOuter" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

ListBox:

```
        <ListBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding WhatsNewList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            </ListBox.Resources>                    
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ExampleClass}">
                    <RadioButton GroupName="Properties" Background="Transparent">
                        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
                            <Binding Path="IsSelected"
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}"
                             Mode="TwoWay" />
                        </RadioButton.IsChecked>
                    </RadioButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I have a button that changes the "SelectedItem" programmatically on the listBox. However, when I click the button it will update the selection but an unwanted side effect is a white square box behind my radio button selection. How do I remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I needed to change the InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey color to Transparent

```
<ListBox.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" Opacity=".4"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey }" Color="Transparent" Opacity=".4"/>
</ListBox.Resources>
```